# Persisting cookies in Azure Static Web App

Tags: angular, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-static-web-app

I have setup a simple solution using Azure: A web API, written in .NET 6, deployed to App Service and a front-end application, written in Angular, deployed to Azure Static Web App. I also configured CORS in the back-end App Service to allow the origin of the front-end application. The API uses cookie authentication and while it works when developing locally, it does not when deployed on Azure. I can see that response to the authentication endpoint returns a Set-Cookie header, however it seems like the cookie is not persisted in the browser (since I can't see it in the dev tools) and all subsequent requests to protected routes fail with a 401 status code. I had the same issue when deploying front-end application to Azure using blob storage. And since I'm new to Azure I'm quite owerwhelmed and don't really know where to look for solution. Is it a misconfiguration on Azure or is it problem with my code (see below)? Any help would be appreciated.

This is the code that configures authentication in my .NET back-end (as you can see it's very basic)

```
            services
                .AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie();

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(config =>
            {
                config.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
            });
```

And then specific endpoints are protected with `[Authorize]` attribute.
There's no specific code in the Angular app for handling user session, since the cookie is meant to be managed by the browser.

EDIT:
Just in case, here are the headers from the authentication response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Sun, 11 Feb 2024 19:20:20 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *** redacted ***
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Identity.Application=CfDJ8ERMzqO_m2BLqQrwjTYL1sAo_a5Pkyd9TDtoraXGkrhdTJwpo6WJ3y_aechrqS4Pz3vsMPwWtn3JhVz93LtODs1Kvz0Ff7rHlwN6NItZOG2BnSRwGAEpz6YBrELFB1nX74Wg9c_uLkCJgCg_A_HkxdrIC06BaUQJkNJSKtN4Q7vSpqZ53FDhuGYobV45FToLFEJDMUu3d3k0Du6XXFMPblZBvI6HTiSYVWjfFf-qPNWZKL0TQtdc9DaX5dyxIxxIuwnubSdfSoBSn9UXDiSE3BcQY86VXkFRsp-DemEZYdtTSN-aWYDEowS6gVDd-TutBC14wh_9QFmpY0UTTfIuYTRmNIcGRWVMz1Vp1uz8WYJEPvWZILoaQfiubOxBtbwvo3KGCfK-cvIfJ9MZLzpRKeIZt1o29VxL-lBwqE_fG99fRWwhP5_9svsuchMyWyiqD4twvQ0Kv4z8XkgahO5F8HJSW4IZ38P1w1p3XuWP9843O6lt7ElqKdaUsypqMlPbAM70Iz4OhmRRoI-FLo49TvbHCZGTouixbMPuJajm8vnv1ca76CjHnAe1e2jlSp1cdyty-JLVrXoFGbSLO4dJv0U9fzzldxQd4as9JngZ33MrbYh0t8eYPWQNqkISacCS5b0Aihx-ehbNBFIo4iqsBrGrVUin6xTb939c4mFpuqhSxpLi0zFlWEC7ax0LN-RVR5f3y9mcsF5Fb-_WE0mcpVCvfRtGUtC1U-Mle9fz7H5N3nTFrwp9HH90ZnwFpM_nBDwo-ToBbY9cp_EoWwPj9zBKFR4dMvdwsdPk4y83PW9nGvNHZrdQO4Sxt35fYD40C2WyWESsXAORRp_jYiFMNpYDbNggZXo08UY_WjI1nYfc; path=/; secure; samesite=lax; httponly
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Answer (score 0):

> then specific endpoints are protected with `[Authorize]` attribute.

Authentication setup seems reasonable, but subsequent requests are not including it.

- Here I have configured the backend .NET application with cookie authentication and including HTTPS enforcement and CORS.

**program.cs:**

```cs
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
            })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultUI()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });

            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.WithOrigins("http://yourfrontenddomain.com")
                               .AllowAnyHeader()
                               .AllowAnyMethod()
                               .AllowCredentials();
                    });
            });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**auth.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  private readonly apiUrl = 'http://your-backend-api-url';
  private loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    // Check if the user is already logged in based on token presence in localStorage
    this.loggedIn.next(this.getToken() !== null);
  }

  login(credentials: { username: string, password: string }): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.apiUrl}/login`, credentials)
      .pipe(
        tap(response => {
          // Save token to localStorage
          localStorage.setItem('token', response.token);
          this.loggedIn.next(true);
        })
      );
  }

  logout(): void {
    // Remove token from localStorage
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    this.loggedIn.next(false);
  }

  getToken(): string | null {
    return localStorage.getItem('token');
  }

  isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.loggedIn.asObservable();
  }
}
```

**Authentication response:**
[image]